# Find query - Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

How do I identify the query that is the problem?

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException: "No result was found for query although at least one ro
w was expected." at /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php line 649 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\ORM\\NoResultExceptio
n: No result was found for query although at least one row was expected. at /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php:649)"}
```

Comment: Where did you find this row? If it is in `prod` environment you should add some additional logging to know that. If you are in `dev` env you can find stacktrace near this row.

Comment: im using dev. what is stacktrace?